# How to validate the integrity of session cookie on each page refresh, and should one?

Tags: node.js, express, session-cookies, next.js

I have a PassportJS authentication set up on my app with strategies for Facebook, Twitter, and Google, along with local. Here's what my authentication route currently looks like:

```
// /routes/auth-routes.js

import connectRedis from 'connect-redis';
import express from 'express';
import session from 'express-session';
import uuidv4 from 'uuid/v4';

import facebook from './auth-providers/facebook';
import google from './auth-providers/google';
import local from './auth-providers/local';
import twitter from './auth-providers/twitter';

const RedisStore = connectRedis(session);
const router = express.Router();

router.use(session({
  name: process.env.SESSION_COOKIE,
  genid: () => uuidv4(),
  cookie: {
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: 'strict',
  },
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  store: new RedisStore({
    host: process.env.REDIS_HOST,
    port: process.env.REDIS_PORT,
    ttl: 1 * 24 * 60 * 60, // In seconds
  }),
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave: false,
}));

// Social auth routes
router.use('/google', google);
router.use('/twitter', twitter);
router.use('/facebook', facebook);
router.use('/local', local);

// Logout
router.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
  const cookieKeys = Object.keys(req.cookies);
  if(cookieKeys.includes(process.env.USER_REMEMBER_COOKIE)) {
    console.log('REMEMBER COOKIE EXISTS!');
    const rememberCookie = process.env.USER_REMEMBER_COOKIE;
    const sessionCookie = process.env.SESSION_COOKIE;
    cookieKeys.forEach((cookie) => {
      if(cookie !== rememberCookie && cookie !== sessionCookie) res.clearCookie(cookie);
    });
    res.redirect(req.query.callback);
  } else {
    console.log('NO REMEMBER');
    req.session.destroy(() => {
      cookieKeys.forEach((cookie) => {
        res.clearCookie(cookie);
      });
      res.redirect(req.query.callback);
    });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

As apparent, I'm using Redis to store session cookies, which are then sent to the server along with all others cookies upon each page-reload. Here's my question:

Is this enough? Shouldn't I be validating the integrity of received session cookie by looking it up against the Redis store? But if I do that on every page load, won't that affect performance adversely? What's the standard way to handle this?

the repo is up at https://github.com/amitschandillia/proost/blob/master/web.

Comment: The Redis store holds all the session data, the cookie usually just the session id. So every request already is looked up in the Redis store.

Comment: If every request is looked up in the store, what happens if a match isn't found, i.e. the cookie has been altered or deleted altogether? Does it return some kind of a flag that I could then use in my route? I tried the PassportJS `isAuthenticated()` method but it seems to return `false` regardless of login state.

Answer (score 0):

It look like you're missing part of the integration with PassportJS with express-session. Like the comment mentioned, express-session will store your session data in the redis store, and its key will be stored in the cookie sent to the user.

But you're logging in your users through passportJS, you need to connect these two middlewares together. From the passportJS docs :

http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/

> Middleware
>
> In a Connect or Express-based application, passport.initialize() middleware is required to initialize Passport. If your application uses persistent login sessions, passport.session() middleware must also be used.

```
app.configure(function() {
  app.use(express.static('public'));
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' }));
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(app.router);
});
```

Comment: I'm not missing any of those parts, you can see the code for yourself on GitHub. Passport does not mention anywhere in its documentation what it does if the session doesn't match. Does it return a flag? Does it refuse login? Nothing. It proceeds to login as if the session never mattered.